# C++ - Class not updating member properly

Tags: c++, vector

I've been programming an adventure game and have everything working up until the movement throughout a two-dimensional array dungeon. The Maps are their own struct, while the Character is a class. One of the member variables of the Character class is a Map, `curMap`, which represents the map the player is currently on. However, in testing in Main.cpp, the works but the map doesn't update properly. Here's the code, after which I'll explain what I've already done.

**Maps.h**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Map {
    vector<string> layout;
    vector<int> exits; //indices in allMaps array
    string name;
    int level;
    Map();
    Map(vector<string> l, vector<int> e, string n, int lvl);

};

extern Map noMap;
extern Map highashPlainsA, highashPlainsB, highashPlainsC; //Highash Plains
extern Map alnwick, alnwickForge, alnwickMarket, alnwickInn; //Alnwick
extern vector<Map> allMaps;

extern vector<string> blankLayout;
extern vector<string> plainsLayoutA, plainsLayoutB, plainsLayoutC; //Highash Plains
extern vector<string> alnwickLayout; //Major Towns
extern vector<string> forgeLayout, marketLayout, innLayout; //Town Buildings
```

**Maps.cpp**

```
#include "Maps.h"

Map::Map() :
    layout(blankLayout),
    exits({0, 0, 0, 0}),
    name("_NO_MAP_"),
    level(0){}

Map::Map(vector<string> l, vector<int> e, string n, int lvl) :
    layout(l),
    exits(e),
    name(n),
    level(lvl){}

Map noMap = Map();
Map highashPlainsA = Map(plainsLayoutA, {4, 3, 2}, "Highash Plains A", 1);
vector<Map> allMaps = {noMap, highashPlainsA};

vector<string> blankLayout =
{"##############################",
 "#                            #",
 "#                            #",
 "#                            #",
 "#                            #",
 "#                            #",
 "#                            #",
 "#                            #",
 "#                            #",
 "##############################"};

vector<string> plainsLayoutA =
{"##########################33##",
 "# G #####   ####### E ####   2",
 "# # # D # #  G      #        2",
 "# # #  ## ####################",
 "# # ##E#   #   G            G#",
 "#E# G#  G                   G#",
 "# #    ##########E############",
 "# #### #DE  G              ED#",
 "# ###D #DE         G       ED#",
 "################111###########"};
```

**Character.h** (I cut out a lot of unimportant code here)

```
#include "Maps.h"
#include <iostream>

class Character {

Map curMap;

public:    
    Character();
    ~Character();
    void SetMap(Map map);
    Map GetMap();
};

extern Character player;
```

**Character.cpp** (Left out said unimportant code here as well)

```
#include "Character.h"

Character::Character() : curMap(highashPlainsA){}

Character::~Character(){}

void Character::SetMap(Map map){
    cout << "OLD MAP NAME: " << curMap.name << "\n";
    curMap = map;
    curMap.layout = map.layout;
    curMap.exits = map.exits;
    curMap.name = map.name;
    curMap.level = map.level;
    cout << "NEW MAP NAME: " << curMap.name << "\n";
}

Map Character::GetMap(){
    return curMap;
}

Character player = Character();
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "Character.h"

int main(){
    player.SetMap(highashPlainsA);
    cout << "\nSIZE OF CURRENT LAYOUT: " << player.GetMap().layout.size() << "\n";
    cout << "SIZE OF PLAINS A: " << plainsLayoutA.size() << "\n";
    cout << "Name of map: " << player.GetMap().name << "\n";
//  cout << "Layout of map: \n" << player.GetMap().layout[0] << "\n" << player.GetMap().layout[1] << "\n" << player.GetMap().layout[2] << "\n"<< player.GetMap().layout[3] << "\n"; // Crashes because for whatever reason the layout size is 0
    return 0;
}
```

**What has been tested:**
In `Character::SetMap()` I even tried changing each individual variable, but shouldn't setting the Map as a whole change all of those values? Additionally, in `Map::Map(vector<string> l, vector<int> e, string n, int lvl)`, I tried it without an initializer list but it still didn't work. I didn't really expect it to, but it was worth a shot I guess.

**The issues:**

*Console Output:*

```
OLD MAP NAME: Highash Plains A
NEW MAP NAME: Highash Plains A

SIZE OF CURRENT LAYOUT: 0
SIZE OF PLAINS A: 10
Name of map: Highash Plains A
```

The character class *does* initialize the `curMap` member, and calls the default constructor to do so. This is intended functionality, because it doesn't matter what map the player is on during setup. However, upon trying to set the map to another precreated Map instance (using `SetMap()`, everything goes downhill from there. According to the console logging, `curMap`'s name was set to the correct name (OLD MAP NAME) and it maintained this when set to the new map. But, the layout returns a null vector whereas a log of the direct size of the target vector gives the proper value. What is going on, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Although you give a lot of information, you are not giving a minimal complete verifiable example. This code does not compile, so we cannot simply reproduce your problem.

Comment: It's not clear what your actual problem is, because there is a lot of unimportant information and not enough important information. Which method does not behave as you expect? `SetMap`?

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius fixed now, compiles and runs in a separate test project.

Comment: @jwimberley Yep, SetMap is the issue. See my "issues" section, as I have updated this to explain the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved: Your problem was that the constructor for HighplainsA was being called before your constructor for plainsLayout. That's because all the constructors are in the global scope, so the order they're run is down to pure luck. It's an example of why having static variables in the global scope is just a terrible idea in general.

When I put debug statements into the constructor for Map, the layout data was empty. This is because the layout data's own constructor had not been executed yet, it was an empty vector. Once you hit main, however, all the constructors have been run, so it appeared that the layout was correct. It just wasn't correct when the Maps were created.

Note that this is an insidious error you can come across if you try and do the right thing and change a raw const char*[] table of strings, into a vector variable. A raw char* table doesn't have a constructor, it's some memory addresses that are determined at compile time, whereas vectors have to call a constructor before they're valid. One way to resolve that issue would have been to store a *reference* to the layout vector in the Map instead of copying it. That way by the time you actually accessed it in main, all the data would have been constructed, and the global values would merely be connecting the dots.

However, don't rely on globals at all, because any time you gave a class type that has a constructor then it must be called at the start of your program. This is especially bad if you use another object that **has** a constructor, such as your vector for layout, and you use that in the constructor for another object that's also in the global scope. It's anyone's guess which one will run first.

Basically, you want to create initialization functions for all data that relies on other data. Then you're able to manually control the order in which the data is initialized.

~~~

Some other advice is to minimize the number of copies of the map you're creating when you access the map:

```
Map &Character::GetMap(){
    return curMap;
}
```

^ this returns a reference to the actual map. You were making another copy every time this was called before, then the copy gets deleted when it was finished being used.

As for storing the map. Currently, Character also has a *copy* of the map. This is not the same thing as your map object that's not in the Character. I don't know if that's by design but you probably didn't intend it to be. The map needs to be used by many classes, e.g. enemies, as well as the character. So each character should not have an entire copy of the map.

References can be stored in the class, but only when the object is created, so if you used a reference to store the map, you  couldn't change it after creating your character. Pointers however are like references, but can be changed while it's running. e.g. you could do this:

```
class Character 
{
    Map *currMap; // * here specifies that it is a pointer

    void setMap(Map &newMap) // & here specifies that it is a reference
    {
        currMap = &newMap; // & here, turns a reference into a pointer
    }


    Map &Character::GetMap() // & here, is returning a reference
    {
        return *curMap; // * here, turns a pointer into a reference
    }
}
```

The pointer *currmap holds the address of a map. A references &newMap is being passed in, then the memory address (&newMap) is being saved in currMap. don't get too confused about the * and &, they're used in slightly different contexts here, so you just need to memorize which one for which occasion. To access a subvalue from a pointer you can do it one of these ways:

```
currMap->name; // get a subvalue from a pointer

(*currMap).name; // * on the left here turns a pointer into a reference
```

Comment: Using pointers still presents the same exact issue. Which is surprising because they should 100% work. **Edit:** I was only getting a copy by design originally because I wanted enemies to stay where they are, but I thought and through and it should be fine if I have random encounter enemies along the empty tiles

Comment: Still, pass in const references even if you're copying. You're currently passing in a copy, then copying the copy, then overwriting the copied members. So you're copying the layout data three times when you only in fact need to copy it once.

Comment: Thanks, this will really help my c++ style in the future. But what do you think is causing the issue with the map member getting a null layout?

Comment: A good technique is to move the print statements backwards, towards the source. If a variable is wrong, output the variable that is being used to make it. e.g. check map.layout.size() at the very start of SetMap. It's zero. You then go one step back from there. Output  the layout.size() of the map you're inputting *into* SetMap. Basically you keep backtracking until you find a value that's correct, then you have your broken link.

Comment: Edit, I solved your problem I'll write it into the answer

Comment: So I would just need to create a function `Map::InitLayout(vector<string> &newLayout)` which sets the layout to be equal to a reference to the specified layout, and then call that in some setup function that handles similar functions? Or am I misinterpreting your answer?

Comment: I would suggest turn all the constructors into "void Init(stuff)" functions, then put them all into a function called "InitMaps()" that you call when main() starts. That way you get complete control of the entire process.

Comment: Just worked on converting the code to fit... instant crash. Not even a preliminary cout statement in main.cpp goes through. Changes I made were creating vectors for the parameters. InitMaps iterates through the vector of Map pointers I created and grabs the respective value from each other vector. (Uses the same index). InitXXXX functions simply set  the map's members to whatever they need to be. Is this just a poor approach? Sorry if I'm bothering you too much...

Comment: Oh my god I am so dense. I did exactly what you said and just put the raw constructor calls into the functions (with default constructor calls outside of the function, of course), and everything compiles and works correctly. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also pass the map to your updateMap function:

```
void Character::UpdateMap(Map map){
curMap = map;//and all other initiations depending on your object
sHandler.ClearScreen(); //In a separate class that does work, is just a call to system("cls")
sHandler.DisplayMap(curMap); //For loop from 0 to (but not including) the size of the layout vector, uses cout to print each row. Works given the correct layout.
```

}

Comment: The UpdateMap is to simply take the map and redisplay to the screen (e.g. whenever a tile is changed from gold ('G') to path (' '). So as long as the map has been set properly, using SetMap, the UpdateMap should work without any special parameters.